# "Invalid value for: Unable to parse" google prediction api request

Tags: json, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-prediction

I am trying to use the Google Prediction API. I have trained my model, and tested a prediction through the web page and it works great. However, I am now trying to use the java api to predict a bunch of records but I keep getting an error

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value for: Unable to parse '[feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5]'.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value for: Unable to parse '[feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5]'."
```

To me it seems like the json creator is not putting quotes around the features, but I am following the sample as close as possible and they don't change or modify the json factory. Here is the credential and prediction building code.

```
private static GoogleCredential authorize() throws Exception {

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(PredictionScopes.PREDICTION))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("p12filefromdevconsole.p12"))
            .build();
    return credential;

}

...
Prediction prediction = new Prediction.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

...
private static Output predict(Prediction prediction, String... features) throws IOException {
    Input input = new Input();
    InputInput inputInput = new InputInput();
    inputInput.setCsvInstance(Collections.<Object>singletonList(features));
    input.setInput(inputInput);
    Output output = prediction.trainedmodels().predict(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_ID, input).execute();
    return output;
}
```

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration and trial and error I solved this problem by using **new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(features))** and not using the **Collections.singletonList(features)**. Here is the modified predict method. Keep in mind my original implementation came directly from the sample on Googles website :(

```
private static Output predict(Prediction prediction, String... features) throws IOException {
    Input input = new Input();
    InputInput inputInput = new InputInput();
    inputInput.setCsvInstance(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(features)));
    input.setInput(inputInput);
    Output output = prediction.trainedmodels().predict(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_ID, input).execute();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: in which version of prediction api, does the InputInput class exists?? I'm unable to find the class in any of the versions. Please help..!!